# Как вывести дату в приложении на angularjs с помощью moment.js?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Как вывести дату с помощью angular.js? Пробовал использовать angular-moment но так и не смог добиться результата.

Comment: Какую дату вам нужно вывести? Текущую или у вас есть дата в какомто одном формате, а вы хотите вывести ее в другом?

Comment: Текущую нужно вывести.

Answer (score 1):

Вы должны сначала создать объект даты в контроллере:

контроллер:

```
function Ctrl($scope)
{
    $scope.date = new Date();
}
```

вывод:

```
<div ng-app ng-controller="Ctrl">
    {{date | date:'yyyy-MM-dd'}}
</div>
```

Comment: Выводит  на странице {{date | date:'yyyy-MM-dd'}}

Comment: @spmpl, Может не там пишите. 
Вот пример: http://jsfiddle.net/RyW9m/

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/s6gy44ea/ вот мой код.

Comment: @spmpl, надо использовать именованные приложения. Демосинтаксис был убран в 1.3.

Comment: @spmpl, какой-то не такой код. Ни разметки нет, ни дат не видно...

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/s6gy44ea/4/ добавил разметку

Answer (score 1):

Как работает у меня ...

1) Услановите локаль. Пример:

```
var App = angular.module("app", [

    'angularMoment'

])

.run([  

    '$rootScope',
    'amMoment',

    function($rootScope, amMoment){

        amMoment.changeLocale('ru');

}])

.controller('someCtrl',['$scope', function ($scope) {
    $scope.date = "2016-02-02 12:30:47";
    /* some code */
}]);
```

2) В шаблоне укажите формат вывода, в примере 'DD MMMM YYYY'

```
<body ng-app="app">
<div ng-controller="someCtrl">
    <span ng-bind="date | amDateFormat:'DD MMMM YYYY'"></span>
    <span ng-bind="date | amDateFormat:'HH:mm:ss'"></span>
</div>
<body>
```

Т.к. у Вас дата текущая, можете попробовать так.

В контроллере:

```
$scope.currentDate = new Date();
```

В шаблоне:

```
<span ng-bind="currentDate | amDateFormat:'DD MMMM YYYY HH:mm:ss'"></span>
```

Проверьте, установлен ли angular-moment https://github.com/urish/angular-moment

Comment: `new Date()` не пройдет, так как во вью все выполняется в контексте scope, а у него, по-умолчанию, нет поля/метода `Date`

Comment: @Grundy, поправил )

Comment: @spmpl, проблему то решили?